# как загрузить репозиторий на Git, если он чужой

Tags: java, git, eclipse

Я клонировала шаблон проекта, завершила его и теперь я хочу загрузить его на Git, как свой, без привязки, чтоб это был чисто мой проект, как мне это сделать?

*Работаю через эклипс*

Comment: Вы имели ввиду загрузить на github или куда вы хотите загрузить?

Comment: удалить `.git`, создать заново через `git init` :)

Comment: `$ git push <url>`

Comment: Igor Golovin да, на гидхаб)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто:

1. Как обычно создайте новый проект на github'е/gitlab'e/bitbucket'e/или куда вы хотите загрузить проект,
2. Добавляйте git.ignore, лицензии, свой readme.md и так далее как в любом новом проекте, делайте git init,
3. Копируйте средствами ОС все файлы в новый проект, кроме .git, делаете commit & push как обычно,

И в общем-то все.

Comment: спасибо большое, если вам не сложно, можно немного поконкретнее, может еще кому понадобиться эта информация.
Может даже в картинках??)) вот с этого места-Добавляйте git.ignore, лицензии, свой readme.md и так далее как в любом новом проекте, делайте git init,

Comment: А для какой системы управления проектами? Github/gitlab/bitbucket? Там картинки совсем разными будут

Comment: Github использую

Comment: Зачем так сложно?! Подключаете дополнительный remote, делаете туда squash-комит, всё.

Comment: А какая разница? Все равно новый репозиторий создавать, делать в нем git init и т.п. Только что добавляется копирование с одной папки в другую.